# cakephp 2x pagination of a different model

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I'm trying to paginate `Workers` which belong(s)To `Job` within a `JobsController`.

```
    class JobsController extends AppController {

var $name = 'Jobs';
var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Js');
var $paginate = array(
    'Worker' => array(
        'limit' => 5, 
        'recursive' => 0, 
        'model' => 'Worker', 
        'order' => array('age' => 'ASC')
    ),      
);

function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid Job.'));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        return;
    }

    $this->Job->id = $id;

    $workers = $this->paginate('Worker', array('Worker.job_id' => $id));
    if ($workers) {
        $this->set('workers', $workers);
    }
}
```

In view.ctp:

```
<?php
$this->Html->script(array('jquery.min'), array('inline' => false));

$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'update' => '#content',
    'evalScripts' => true,
));
?>

<?php if (isset($workers)): ?>

    <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('model' => 'Worker')); ?>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Info</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($workers as $worker): ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $worker['Worker']['age']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $worker['Worker']['info']; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>

    <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('model' => 'Worker')); ?>
    <p>
    <?php
    echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
        'model' => 'Worker',
        'format' => __('Page %page% of %pages%, showing %current% records out of %count% total.')
    ));
    ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>
```

I'm getting the correct list of workers. But the links generated by `numbers` are not working. They look like /view/2/page:2/sort:Worker.age/direction:ASC
What am I doing wrong? cakephp version is 2.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your view action, by setting the order at run time.

```
$this->paginate['Worker']['order'] = array('Worker.age' => 'ASC')
```

Now your function look like this

```
function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid Job.'));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        return;
    }

    $this->Job->id = $id;

    $this->paginate['Worker']['order'] = array('Worker.age' => 'ASC');
    $workers = $this->paginate('Worker', array('Worker.job_id' => $id));
    if ($workers) {
        $this->set('workers', $workers);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: the generated links then look like /view/2/page:2/ and don't work either

Comment: if you want to do ajax pagination over here, you need to put some conditions to work the things.by default it will take `default` layout. so you've to make that one `ajax` during ajax pagination. and also what is `#content` here, i can't see any html tag with `id` `content`. can you please ensure whether it's sending any ajax call when you click on pagianation numbers.

Comment: there is still an error that the requested address /view/2/page:2/ was not found without ajax

Comment: Try to use with querystring paramters, may be this way you can.
`var $paginate = array(
    'Worker' => array(
        'limit' => 5, 
        'recursive' => 0, 
        'model' => 'Worker', 
        'order' => array('age' => 'ASC'), 'paramType' => 'querystring'
    ),      
);`

Comment: can you put the script that you're using for generating the `view` link in your view files